# Load related entities with a single .Include() in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, lazy-loading, eager-loading

Is there a better way to load all the related entities?

Below is the ScholarshipRequest class which also has Scholarship, Status, Student, Program and User.

```
public class ScholarshipRequest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime ApplicationDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ActionDate { get; set; }
        public Scholarship Scholarship { get; set; }
        public Program Program { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

I am just posting Scholarship class here, rest are similar.

```
public class Scholarship
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The below code works fine but **is there a better way where i can use a single .Include() to load them all or may be some other way?**

```
ScholarshipRequestRepository repo = new ScholarshipRequestRepository(dBContext);
List<ScholarshipRequest> stdList = repo.Collection()
                .Include("Status").Include("Student").Include("User").Include("Scholarship")
                .Where(x => x.User.Id == userId).ToList();
```

Comment: Short answer: no. Side note: it's recommended to use the lambda version of `Include`.

Comment: @GertArnold what about Lazy Loading ?

Comment: That's a different loading strategy quite different than `Include`.

Comment: @GertArnold So can that method be used instead of using  `Include` at all to load all the related entities at once?